# Foreach strpos problem. Find string in another string

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, substr, strpos

I'm trying to get this script to work.

The idea is that if the input string `($query)` doesn't start with `'/t'` AND contains one of the `$trigger` words, an `$error` is set.

I can't get this to work and I'm not sure why.

```
<?php

    $error = false;

    $triggers = array('sell', 'buy', 'trade', 'trading');

    $query = 'buying stuff';

    if (!empty($query)) {

        if (substr($query, 0, 2) != '/t') {

            foreach ($triggers as $trigger) {

                if (strpos($query, $trigger)) {

                    $error = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if ($error) {

        echo "fail";
    }
    else {

        echo "pass";
    }

?>
```

That should have triggered the error but it doesn't seem to be.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the function `strpos` fails to find the string it returns `false`. Also note that if the search string is found at the very beginning a `0` is returned.

Change

```
if (strpos($query, $trigger)) {
```

to

```
if (strpos($query, $trigger) !== false) {
```

Comment: @imoda I would also add a `break` after `$error = true;` to safe some unneeded iterations.

Answer (score 1):

change this to

```
if (strpos($query, $trigger) !==false ) {
```

checkout how [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) works

Comment: Double quotes for what? It is not a tab-char

Comment: Double or single quotes there doesn't make a difference.

Comment: sorry guys did not see the nature of slash

Answer (score 1):

here is the problem :

```
  if (strpos($query, $trigger)) {
```

This evaluates to 0 if string is found at index 0, which causes IF statement to be false
so use

`(strpos($query,$trigger) !== false )`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    $error = false;

    $triggers = array('sell', 'buy', 'trade', 'trading');

    $query = 'buying stuff';

    if (!empty($query)) {

        if (substr($query, 0, 2) != '/t') {

            foreach ($triggers as $trigger) {

                if (strpos($query, $trigger) !== false) {

                    $error = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if ($error) {

        echo "fail";
    }
    else {

        echo "pass";
    }

?>
```

Please use the "`break`" keyword, along with the proper checking.

Hope it helps.